# Converting Object HTMLImageElement to text string?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net

I have an odd thing going on that I'm trying to find a work around for (not by choice but I HAVE to do it). I have a javascript function that shows or hides a table row. Someone else wrote it. How it works is that when you click on an image in a table row it shows a row underneath it. Clicking the image again collapses the row. The image code for it is simple:

```
<img blah blah blah onClick="ShowHide(this);">
```

What I am trying to do is capture that img element and attributes and send it as a query string so that when the page does a postback I can call the javascript function ShowHide(this) in the code behind and pass it the image properties. That way the row will show on page load. Does that make sense? So what I have right now is:

```
function postbackwithModal(){
    //image properties is what I need to figure out
    window.location = "/Products/ProductDetail.aspx?element=" + imageProperties;
}
```

and then in the code behind:

```
string element = Request.QueryString["element"];
        if (!element.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "ShowHide(" + element     + ");", true);
        }
```

The ShowHide() function looks like this:

```
function ShowHide(Element) {
    var rowIndex = $(Element).parent().parent()[0].sectionRowIndex;
    var item = $(Element).parent().parent().parent().children()[rowIndex + 1];
    if ($(item).is(":visible") == true) {
        $(item).hide(0, function () { $(Element).attr('src', '../Images/plus.png'); });
    }
    else {
        $(item).show(0, function () { $(Element).attr('src', '../Images/minus.png'); });
        // Loop though the images and set the src value to be the custom handler endpoint.
        var ImageContainer = $(item).children().children().children()[3];
        var Images = $(ImageContainer).find('img');

    }

    globalPlus = Element;
}
```

Comment: @pbfy0 No it does not. It is populated on the page with an item template.

Comment: @pbfy0 I have to say thank you. You gave me an idea of giving each image a unique ID which allowed me to come up with some jquery/javascript combination to do what I needed to do.